# How can I inner join two csv files in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have two csv files.

File one has two columns:

```
DD1 abct
DD2 geate
DD3 watec
DD4 wwwca21
DD5 bate789
```

File two has one column:

```
abct
geate
bate789
```

I want to get a truncated file one to include those that matched with file two, i.e.

```
DD1 abct
DD2 geate
DD5 bate789
```

Could you mind to let me know how to do it with R?

New to R.

Comment: The correct term for this is an "inner join". Calling it "truncating" in the title is not going to help the future search efforts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, read the files with the `read.table`:

```
file1 <- read.table("file1.csv", col.names=c("FOO", "BAR"))
file2 <- read.table("file2.csv", col.names=c("BAR"))
```

Then merge them:

```
merged <- merge(file1, file2)
```

And write the result:

```
write.table(merged, "merged.csv")
```

Comment: Two more points: for more sophisticated operations, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: And for really large files, R might not be the best option, command line utils like `join` (or `awk` / `sed`) will be faster, I think.

Answer (score 0):

This is a direct way to do it by doing %in%.  This will be about the fastest way entirely within R.

read in the files

```
datf1 <- read.table("file1.csv") #two column file
datf2 <- read.table("file2.csv") #one column file
```

select the rows you want... %in% makes a logical vector that is the length of the first argument and is TRUE when an item is in both of the arguments and FALSE otherwise.

```
datf1 <- datf1[datf1[,2] %in% datf2[,1],]
```

write it out... I changed the file name from file1 because you really shouldn't overwrite your original data and make a new file1.

```
write.table(datf1, "file3.csv", sep = ',', row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```